# which solution is best performance wise

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, css-animations

I am building a small game in javascript to learn object oriented programming in javascript. In it, units move around and do basic stuff.

Animations happens every 20 millisecond. Collision detection should happen every 100 millisecond.

It seems to be faster to have a single setInterval running in the document, as compared to a new setInterval every time a unit is instantiated. So I am doing this. Source: http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-2/.

But now I have to do collision detection, as well as animation. I see two solutions:

Solution 1:

```
window.setInterval(AnimateFunc,20);

function AnimateFunc(){
    for (i = 0; i < UnitArray.length; i++){
        UnitArray[i].Behaviour();     // Every unit in my array of units behaviour function is called. ex: add 2 pixels to unit.style.top.
    }
    CollisionDetectionCounter += 1;   // Globale variable
    if (CollisionDetectionCounter === 5){
        CollisionDetectionFunc();
        CollisionDetectionCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

With this solution the single setInterval call in the document is preserved. But every second 50 variable incrementations and 50 comparisons is made.

Solution 2:

```
window.setInterval(AnimateFunc,20);
window.setInterval(CollisionDetectionFunc, 100);

function AnimateFunc(){
    for (i = 0; i < UnitArray.length; i++){
        UnitArray[i].Behaviour();
    }
}
function CollisionDetectionFunc(){
    // Perform collision detection between all units curently on the field.
}
```

With this solution we prevent the 50 incrementations/comparisons but there is now two setInterval functions in play.

So which solution would be best, do you think?

I realize it probably won't matter much. I will probably make other decisions that will screw my game up way worse performance wise down the line, but I am curious :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now I have no business in answering this question at all, but I feel like solution 2 is better because of separation of concerns.  Your animation and collision code should be separate.  Animating shouldn't update some global and possibly check for collisions.  It should just animate.

Comment: My two-penneth: `setInterval()` timing is not particularly accurate. Use a single timing loop and calculate what needs to be done based on elapsed time since start.

Comment: Test it yourself, it's always the best. I like the solution 1 better because setIntervals can sometimes get out of sync. If you plan to do something more serious there, I'd suggest completely dropping the setInterval and use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead.

Comment: Just make sure to use the `timeline` in Chrome dev tools and it will show you that @Shomz is correct, requestAnimationFrame will drop unwanted lag and maintain the most consistent framerate. The other issue will be in rendering or `paint`-ing, you want to look at using `translate3d` for modern devices to be able to hardware accelerate.

Comment: Uh, 50 *increments* and 50 *comparisons*? How many nanoseconds will this take of your precisous time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless those exact timing constraints are your hard limits, I would suggest `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`. But if you must use `setInterval`, then I would recommend an approach that's a hybrid of your two setups:

```
function AnimateFunc(){
    for (i = 0; i < UnitArray.length; i++){
        UnitArray[i].Behaviour();
    }
}

function CollisionDetectionFunc(){
    // Perform collision detection between all units curently on the field.
}

function TickFunc() {
    AnimateFunc();
    CollisionDetectionCounter += 1;   // Globale variable
    if (CollisionDetectionCounter === 5){
        CollisionDetectionFunc();
        CollisionDetectionCounter = 0;
    }
}
window.setInterval(TickFunc, 20);
```

This lets you control things off of a single timer. That's not so much a performance concern as a syncing concern: multiple timers can drift relative to one another, and it doesn't sound like you want this to happen. But it also lets you maintain separation of concerns: there's a function for animation, a function for collisions, and a function that coordinates them.

This can also be adapted to use `requestAnimationFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `requestAnimationFrame` instead,  for more Information see:

- [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)
- [requestAnimationFrame for Smart Animating](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

Your code could look similar to this:

```
var lastCollisionDetection;
var requestId;

function animate(time) {
  if (lastCollisionDetection + 100 > time) {
    lastCollisionDetection = time;

    // TODO: collision detection
  }

  // TODO: update objects - you might want to check the passed time here as well

  requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

lastCollisionDetection = window.performance.now();
requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```